# GridView Non-Visible Row Showing up in Empty Data Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview, hidden-field

I have a custom GridView that will show 6 rows of data as a default (regardless of how many rows) with a pager at the bottom.  This Gridview is used for numerous unique pages.  On one page, I have a column that I set to hidden (width 0 and Css-Display=none) that I need -- another part of program depends on it being set that way.

The column is NOT visible in rows where there is data (as it shouldn't be).  However, the column is showing up in the empty rows as an empty column (should not be visible).  How would I go about making the EMPTY rows hide the COLUMN as well?

Comment: Are you trying to hide a row or a column?

Comment: Just a column within the empty rows.

Comment: And the column is being hidden on the rows with data too? Sorry, just trying to understand the problem.

Comment: I'll edit to make it more clear.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. If this column is never supposed to be displayed, why does it have to be a column? Do you need the value in the column or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my GridView_DataBound function, the cells were being generated for each column that existed -- how it filled in the empty cells.  I added the if statement to check if the field was supposed to be  hidden, and ensure the autogenerated cell was hidden as well.

```
foreach (DataControlField field in _gridView.Columns)
{
    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
    cell.Text = "&nbsp;";

    if (field.ItemStyle.CssClass == "hideGridColumn")
        cell.Visible = false;

    row.Cells.Add(cell);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have some custom implementation to display empty rows (so 6 are always displayed) that probably uses a different template than the regular rows or possibly no template at all.  The problem is most likely that your empty row definition is not applying the width and css properties to the hidden column.

Can you post the how you implemented the feature to show empty rows?

Comment: You were right.  There was some custom implementation I didn't notice in the code for these empty rows.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted this if any one still searching simple answer for this Question

You can use the OnRowCreated event of GridView and specify the columnspan value of the empty row as number of visible column. See the below sample code

```
protected void grd_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
             if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow)
                e.Row.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = 7; // number of visible columns;
        }
```